# Tkinter issue regarding dynamically uncheck CheckBoxes

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

In Tkinter (Python) I try to dynamically uncheck a CheckBox when an another CheckBox is checked but the behavior is rather erratic.

1. If the first box is checked and i check the second one: the second box checks for few seconds then it unchecks. The event related to the second CheckBox doesn't trigger.
2. If the second box is checked and i check the first one: the behavior is correct as it uncheck the second one and check the first one. The event related to the first CheckBox does trigger.
3. If there's no single box checked and I check one box at the time the events do trigger normally.

My code :

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.entry1 = tk.Canvas(self.frame, width=100, height=100, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, bg="green", relief='solid')
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.entry2 = tk.Canvas(self.frame, width=100, height=100, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, bg="red", relief='solid')

        self.check_var1 = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.check_var1.set(True)
        self.check_box1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Show Green", variable=self.check_var1, command=lambda: self.toggle_entries(self.check_var1))
        self.check_box1.pack()

        self.check_var2 = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.check_box2 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Show Red", variable=self.check_var2, command=lambda: self.toggle_entries(self.check_var2))
        self.check_box2.pack()

        self.check_var1.trace_add('write', self.check_var_changed)
        self.check_var2.trace_add('write', self.check_var_changed)

        self.toggle_entries(self.check_var1)

    def toggle_entries(self, var):
        if var is self.check_var1:
            if var.get():
                self.entry1.grid()
                self.entry2.grid_remove()
                self.check_var2.set(False) 
        elif var is self.check_var2:
            if var.get():
                self.entry2.grid()
                self.entry1.grid_remove()
                self.check_var1.set(False) 

    def check_var_changed(self, *args):
        if self.check_var1.get():
            self.check_var2.set(False)
        elif self.check_var2.get():
            self.check_var1.set(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Any ideas of why this function`toggle_entries` doesn't work properly?

Comment: Are you trying to implement mutually exclusive options? If so, it sounds like what you're looking for is a [radiobutton](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-radio-button/), not a `Checkbutton`

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was `check_var_changed` :

```
def check_var_changed(self, *args):
   if self.check_var1.get():
     self.check_var2.set(False)
   elif self.check_var2.get():
     self.check_var1.set(False)
```

interfering with the `toggle_entries` function creating a loop. I removed `check_var_changed` alongside with

```
self.check_var1.trace_add('write', self.check_var_changed)
self.check_var2.trace_add('write', self.check_var_changed)
```

and now it works perfectly. I leave this post up in case someone encounters the same issue.

Comment: I feel like I should point out again that if you want mutually exclusive options, the typically approach is to use a group of `Radiobutton` widgets. Using `Checkbuttons` for this is bad UX (even though it works) because most users expect to be able to select *one or more options* when presented with a group of checkboxes. Conversely, radio buttons immediately indicated to the user that only one option is selectable at a time. Clicking a checkbox only to have it un-check another checkbox violates the [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to remove both `check_var_changed()` function,   `self.check_var1.trace_add` and `self.check_var2.trace_add`.

Screenshot:

[image]